# html5 progress bar not working/modified by angular

Tags: html, angularjs

html5 progress bar `<progress value="5" max="100"></progress>` when used in angular gets replaced by angular classes. There is also a angular's own progress bar which uses the same tags. Some other elements like slider of html5 do not get interfered by angular & work well by themselves.

Is there a way to use the simple html5 progress bar in angular? or is it a bad practice or something? I like html5 progress bar, using it is pretty straight forward. Or using angular progress bar is a better solution?

Comment: Angular UI's own progress bar work but not html5's progress bar. Both use <progress></progress> tags.

Comment: hi did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Several years later ... I had the same problem where HTML
`<progress></progress>`
was being compiled to
`<div class=progress></div>`

This was caused by one of my included modules -  Bootstrap [progress](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/progressbar/progress.html)

If you have an issue like this where angular is compiling something as a directive, you can tell angular to ignore it using [ngNonBindable](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

`<progress ng-non-bindable></progress>`